# Knowledge transfer in regularised linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

By default all regularised linear regression techniques of scikit-learn pull the model coefficients `w` towards 0 with increased `alpha`. Is it possible to instead pull the coefficients towards some predefined values? In my application I do have such values that have been obtained from a previous analysis of a similar but much larger dataset. In other words, can I [transfer the knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_transfer) from one model to another?

The [documentation of `LassoCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) says:

> The optimization objective for Lasso is:
>
> ```
> (1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||_1
> ```

In theory it's easy to incorporate previously obtained coefficients `w0` by changing the above to

> ```
> (1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w - w0||_1
> ```

The problem is that the actual optimisation is carried out by the Cython function [`enet_coordinate_descent`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fcb706a7c0074a16bd472ca284145be2e0f7c936/sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.pyx#L149) (called via [`lasso_path`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fcb706a7c0074a16bd472ca284145be2e0f7c936/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L128) and [`enet_path`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fcb706a7c0074a16bd472ca284145be2e0f7c936/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L128)). If I want to change it, do I need to fork, modify, and recompile the whole `sklearn.linear_model` package or reimplement the whole optimisation routine?

#### Toy example

The following code defines a dataset `X` with 4 features and a matching response vector `y`.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV

n = 50
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 8, n)
x2 = np.random.normal(8, 6, n)

X = np.column_stack([x1, x1 ** 2, x2, x2 ** 2])
y = .8 * x1 + .2 * x2 + .7 * x2**2 + np.random.normal(0, 3, n)

cv = LassoCV(cv=10).fit(X, y)
```

The resulting coefficients and `alpha` are

```
>>> print(cv.coef_)
[ 0.46262115  0.01245427  0.          0.70642803]
>>> print(cv.alpha_)
7.63613474003
```

If we had prior knowledge regarding two of the coefficients `w0 = np.array([.8, 0, .2, 0])`, how could that be incorporated?

#### My final solution, based on @lejlot's answer

Rather than using vanilla GD I eventually arrived at using [Adam](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/?#adam).
This solution just fits a lasso for a given value of `alpha`, it does not find the value `alpha` by itself like `LassoCV` does (but it's easy to add a layer of CV on top of it).

```py
from autograd import numpy as np
from autograd import grad
from autograd.optimizers import adam

def fit_lasso(X, y, alpha=0, W0=None):
    if W0 is None:
        W0 = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

    def l1_loss(W, i):
        # i is only used for compatibility with adam
        return np.mean((np.dot(X, W) - y) ** 2) + alpha * np.sum(np.abs(W - W0))

    gradient = grad(l1_loss)

    def print_w(w, i, g):
        if (i + 1) % 250 is 0:
            print("After %i step: w = %s" % (i + 1, np.array2string(w.T)))

    W_init = np.random.normal(size=(X.shape[1], 1))
    W = adam(gradient, W_init, step_size=.1, num_iters=1000, callback=print_w)
    return W

n = 50
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 8, n)
x2 = np.random.normal(8, 6, n)

X = np.column_stack([x1, x1 ** 2, x2, x2 ** 2])
y = .8 * x1 + .2 * x2 + .7 * x2 ** 2 + np.random.normal(0, 3, n)

fit_lasso(X, y, alpha=30)
fit_lasso(X, y, alpha=30, W0=np.array([.8, 0, .2, 0]))
```

```
After 250 step: w = [[ 0.886  0.131  0.005  0.291]]
After 500 step: w = [[ 0.886  0.131  0.003  0.291]]
After 750 step: w = [[ 0.886  0.131  0.013  0.291]]
After 1000 step: w = [[ 0.887  0.131  0.013  0.292]]

After 250 step: w = [[ 0.868  0.129  0.728  0.247]]
After 500 step: w = [[ 0.803  0.132  0.717  0.249]]
After 750 step: w = [[ 0.801  0.132  0.714  0.249]]
After 1000 step: w = [[ 0.801  0.132  0.714  0.249]]
```

The results are quite similar on this example, but you can at least tell that specifying a `W0` prevented the model from killing the third coefficient.
The effect is only apparent if you use an `alpha` > 20 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short - yes, you need to do it by hand by recompiling everything. Scikit-learn is not a library for **customizable** ML models. It is about providing simple, typical models with easy to use interface. If you want customization you should look for things like tensorflow, keras etc. or at least - autograd. In fact with autograd this is extremely simple, since you can write your code with numpy and use autograd to compute gradients.

```
X = ... your data
y = ... your targets
W0 = ... target weights
alpha = ... pulling strength 
lr = ... learning rate (step size of gradient descent)


from autograd import numpy as np
from autograd import grad


def your_loss(W):
  return np.mean((np.dot(X, W) - y)**2) + alpha * np.sum(np.abs(W - W0))

g = grad(your_loss)

W = np.random.normal(size=(X.shape[1], 1))
for i in range(100):
   W = W - lr * g(W)

print(W)
```